# SQL QUOTENAME adding single quotes and a comma

Tags: sql, function, quotename

I have a basic table which outputs.

```
field1
  a
  b
  c
```

Then i want to add single quotes and a comma so currently i have a simple QUOTENAME.

```
QUOTENAME(field1,'''')
```

Which outputs the following results.

```
field1
  'a'
  'b'
  'c'
```

But i cant figure out how to get the QUOTENAME to output results like this.

```
field1
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
QUOTENAME(field1,'''')+','
```

Comment: Perfect! will tick as best answer in 12 minutes!

Answer (score 9):

I know you got your answer but just wanted to make an addition if someone else looks at this and is wondering how to get rid of the last comma after the last value in case they are using the resultset for a dynamic query.

```
Declare @MyString nvarchar(max)
select @MyString += QuoteName (field1.'''') + ','
from YourTable Name

Set @MyString = left (@MyString, Len ( @MyString) - 1 )
```

And to view the results a

```
Print @MyString
```

can be added to evaluate the results.

Hope this helps others looking for this logic when using the quotename and needing that last comma removed :-)

Answer (score 3):

that doesnt work
you dont initialize @MyString 
so concatenating anything with null will be null

but using this aproach you dont need to initialize it

```
DECLARE @MyString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @MyString = COALESCE(@MyString+ ',', '') + QUOTENAME(field1, '''') 
FROM    YourTable Name
```